# React native flatlist to tab screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a flatlist which lists customers item. When I press on each item, it will navigate to the main screen tab, which contains 3 tab screens:

- customer's info
- customer's current address
- customer's billing address.

These 3 screens get data from different APIs but depends on customer ID.
How can I pass flatlist keys to those screens, in order to display data from any API ?

Here is my code at the moment:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import TabNavigator from 'react-native-tab-navigator';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const deviceW = Dimensions.get('window').width

const basePx = 768

function px2dp(px) {
  return px *  deviceW / basePx
}

class Info extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Customer info:_____
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class currentadd extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          current address is:_____
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class billingadd extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Billing address is:_____
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }


export default class CustomerDetail extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: `${navigation.state.params.custid}`,
    }
  };


  state= {
    selectedTab: 'info'
  }; 

  render() {
    return (
      <TabNavigator style={styles.container}>
        <TabNavigator.Item
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'info'}
          title="Customer General Info"
          selectedTitleStyle={{color: "#3496f0"}}
          renderIcon={() => <Icon name="user" size={px2dp(22)} color="#666"/>}
          renderSelectedIcon={() => <Icon name="user" size={px2dp(22)} color="#3496f0"/>}
          onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab: 'info'})}>
          <Info />
        </TabNavigator.Item>
        <TabNavigator.Item
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'currentadd'}
          title="current address"
          selectedTitleStyle={{color: "#3496f0"}}
          renderIcon={() => <Icon name="usd" size={px2dp(22)} color="#666"/>}
          renderSelectedIcon={() => <Icon name="home" size={px2dp(22)} color="#3496f0"/>}
          onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab: 'currentadd'})}>
          <currentadd/>
        </TabNavigator.Item>
        <TabNavigator.Item
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'billingadd'}
          title="billing address"
          selectedTitleStyle={{color: "#3496f0"}}
          renderIcon={() => <Icon name="usd" size={px2dp(22)} color="#666"/>}
          renderSelectedIcon={() => <Icon name="phone" size={px2dp(22)} color="#3496f0"/>}
          onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab: 'billingadd'})}>
          <billingadd/>
        </TabNavigator.Item>
      </TabNavigator>
    );
  }
}
...stylesheet here
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could apply the following example, in your application, the main idea is send the identifier of your object(ID) to others child objects, so in order to do that, you can catch this ID when an action is performed on your component, for example:

```
class Decks extends Component { 
   render () {

        const { decks } = this.props;

        return (
            <View>
                {Object.keys(decks).map((key) => {
                    return (
                        <View key={key} style={styles.deck}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DeckProfile', { 
                                title: decks[key].title
                                })}>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    )
                })}
          </View>
        )
    }
}
```

So, in the 'navigate' function is sent the Component that will be displayed at the moment to do the press action and also the ID of the main component(in this case 'title') will be sent too. Will be necessary define this in the MainNavigator, according the parameters used before, in this case 'title':

```
const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({

  DeckProfile: {
    screen: DeckProfile,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: navigation.state.params.title,
      headerTintColor: white,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: lightPurp,
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try then let's see that.

Comment: Oh! another thing is that, I sent an item(custid) from my flatlist screen. I could get custid displayed on the title. My screen layout looks like this. 1. CustomerList screen(used flatlist)---->2. CustomerDetail screen which will have 3 tab navigation screens and those screen will get customer infomation from mysql api. I just wonder how can I pass custid to tab screens so that I can get mysql api json data for selected customer id.

Comment: If you could give some sample like the case mentioned above would be very appreciated. Thank you again @Lucero.

Answer (score 0):

:) , Okey , so you have the 'custid' in the 'CustomerDetail' screen and the tab screens need get this information(custid), in order to pass this information, you could use the `this.props.navigation.state.params.title` (in your case could be 'custid' instead of 'title'), and the flow looks like this:

**CustomerList.js Component:**

```
class CustomerList extends Component { 
   render () {

        const { customers } = this.props;

        return (
            <View>
                {Object.keys(customers).map((key) => {
                    return (
                        <View key={key} style={styles.customer}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CustomerDetail', { 
                                custid: customers[key].custid
                                })}>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    )
                })}
          </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.js Component:**

```
const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({

  CustomerDetail: {
    screen: CustomerDetail,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      custid: navigation.state.params.custid,
      headerTintColor: white,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: lightPurp,
      }
    })
  }
```

**CustomerDetail.js Component:**

class CustomerDetail extends Component {

```
render () {
    const { customers } = this.props;
    let custid = this.props.navigation.state.params.custid;

    return(
        <TabNavigator style={styles.container}>
           <TabNavigator.Item
            title={customers[custid].name}
           </TabNavigator.Item>
        </TabNavigator>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Lucero. Let me try then let you know the result.

Comment: Well, Here are my components:

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Login from './src/components/Login';
import Home from './src/components/Home';
import Dashboard from './src/components/Dashboard';
import Customer from './src/components/Customer';
import CustomerDetail from './src/components/CustomerDetail';

const MyApp = StackNavigator(

    {
      Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null
        },
      },
      Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null
        },
      },
      Dashboard: {
        screen: Dashboard,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'Dashboard'
        },
      },
      Customer: {
        screen: Customer,
        navigationOptions: {
          title:'List of customers'
        }
      },
      CustomerDetail: {
        screen: CustomerDetail,
        navigationOptions: {
          title:'Customer Detail'
        }
      }
    });

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyApp />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Lucero I almost done with this simple app. just try to find the way to get information on every tab. I have not try using separated components for customer details

Answer (score 0):

Customer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Alert, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import { Navigator } from 'react-navigation';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';


export default class Customer extends Component {

  state = {
    loading: false,
    data: []
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.searchCust('M000');
  }

  onPressSearch = term => {
    if(term == '')
      {
        Alert.alert("Enter to search");
      }
    else
    {
      this.searchCust(term);
    }
  }

  searchCust = term => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

      const url = `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app/customerlist.php?term=${term}`;
        fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              data: res.results,
              error: res.error || null,
              loading: false,
            });
          })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({ error });
      });
  }

  goToCustomerDetail = (item) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("CustomerDetail",{item});      //Alert.alert(item);//
  }
  render() {
    const { loading, data } = this.state;
    const { customers } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
        <SearchBar
          loading={loading}
          onPressSearch={this.onPressSearch}
        />

        <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              const badge = {
                value: `☆ ${item.custstar}`, {/* d is a database field*/}
                badgeContainerStyle: { right: 10, backgroundColor: '#56579B' },
                badgeTextStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
              };  

              return (
                 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goToCustomerDetail.bind(this, item.custid)}>
                  <ListItem
                    style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                    roundAvatar
                    title={`${item.custid}`}
                    subtitle={item.custname}
                    avatar={{ uri: item.imageurl }}
                    badge={badge}
                    containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 1 }}

                  />
                 </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            }
            }
            keyExtractor={item => item.custid}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
            onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          />
        </List>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SearchBar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = { term: '' };

  render() {
    const {
      containerStyle,
      searchTextStyle,
      buttonStyle
    } = styles;

    return (
      <View style={containerStyle}>
        <TextInput
          style={searchTextStyle}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          placeholder='Search'
          onChangeText={term => this.setState({ term })}
          value={this.state.term}
          autoFocus={ true }
        />
        <Button
          buttonStyle={buttonStyle}
          icon={{name: 'search', size: 24}}
          title={this.props.loading ? 'Searching...' : 'Search'}
          onPress={() => this.props.onPressSearch(this.state.term)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    marginTop: 25,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  searchTextStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#BE3A31'
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    height: 30,
    marginBottom: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#BE3A31'
  }
};


export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, so you have the following scenario: The 'CustomerDetail' component have three tabs, that needs get the 'custid' from 'CustomerDetail' parent component, so is necessary that 'CustomerDetail' component knows this information, in order to do that, you have created 'App.js' component, where you have been defined 'CustomerDetail' into StackNavigator, 'CustomerDetail' component get this information, just putting the following lines of code:

**BEFORE**

```
CustomerDetail: {
        screen: CustomerDetail,
        navigationOptions: {
          title:'Customer Detail'
        }
      }
```

**AFTER**

```
CustomerDetail: {
    screen: CustomerDetail,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title:'Customer Detail',
      custid: navigation.state.params.custid
    })
  }
```

Right now, you will be able to get the 'custid', information in your tabs children from 'CustomerDetail' component, through this line:

```
class CustomerDetail extends Component {

render () {
    const { customers } = this.props;
    let custid = this.props.navigation.state.params.custid;

    return(
        <TabNavigator style={styles.container}>
           <TabNavigator.Item
            title={customers[custid].name}
           </TabNavigator.Item>
        </TabNavigator>
    )
}
```